# testing decorator with pytest using weird syntax

Tags: python, decorator, pytest, coroutine

so I wanted to test a decorator that gives you a coroutine that's primed up (so I don't have to do `coroutine.send(None)` ).

Details can be found [here](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/coroutine.py). David Beazley's example)

so in conftest.py I created a function wrapper that's a pytest fixture, which gives me a raw coroutine, if that makes sense.

the reason I am doing this is because pytest will take anything after yield keyword as teardown codes and I don't want that. so I wrapp up a raw coroutine myself.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def create_coroutine_func():

    def grep(pattern):
        print "Looking for %s" % pattern
        while True:
            line = (yield)
            if pattern in line:
                print line
    return grep
```

now in my test file I have a rather simple test:

```
    from something.decorators import *
    import pytest

1    def test_coroutine(create_coroutine_func):
2        coro_func = create_coroutine_func()
3        coro_wrapper = coroutine(coro_func)
4    
5        assert callable(coro_wrapper)
```

ok that's it. pytest complained:

> create_coroutine() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pattern'

then I went ahead edited line 2:

```
coro_func = create_coroutine_func("python") # match anything has 'python' in it.
```

now test passed.

now I a bit confused with decorators now.

So in my example grep takes an argument; when I call my grep function wrapper, I need to give the function wrapper an argument as well although it doesn't take any argument itself? is this how decorator works?

Comment: I *think* pytest fixtures may be confusing things here. When you pass a fixture as an argument into a test function, the *return* value is the argument. So in your case line 2 `create_coroutine_func is grep`.

Comment: @JacquesKvam  I might be wrong, did you mean ‘create_coroutine_func’ is ‘grep’ when I passed it into test? I would think the return value of ‘create_coroutine_func’ would be ‘grep’ wouldn’t it? When you say the return value is the argument what’s the argument here?

Comment: `create_coroutine_func` (no parens) is `grep` because `pytest` has called `create_coroutine_func()` (note: parens) when converted it to a fixture.

Comment: @phd ok now I think I get what you meant. thanks for the help! it is a bit confusing in the first place.

Comment: @JacquesKvam  thanks I understand what you mean now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPD: As @jacques-kvam pointed out in the comments, when you pass a fixture as an argument into a test function, the return value of the fixture IS the argument's value. So in your case, line 2 `create_coroutine_func` is `grep`.

This misunderstanding of the pytest fixtures is probably the main reason of misuse of the values in the test function itself.

Once this is clear, here is my original answer:

---

Here, you *call* your function on line 2 in `create_coroutine_func()`. This is why it expects the parameter to be passed.

What you actually need, if you want to wrap the function into a decorator, is to operate on the function-object itself. It do not call it, but pass it as a value to the decorator:

```
def test_coroutine(create_coroutine_func):
    coro_wrapper = coroutine(create_coroutine_func)
    assert callable(coro_wrapper)
    coro_wrapper("python")
```

This is how the decorators work: they take one function as an argument and return another (or the same) function as the result.

---

PS: This same test can be written in a more nice syntax:

```
from something.decorators import *
import pytest

def test_coroutine(create_coroutine_func):

    @coroutine
    def grep(pattern):
        print "Looking for %s" % pattern
        while True:
            line = (yield)
            if pattern in line:
                print line       

    assert callable(grep)
    grep("python")
```

Note that the decorator usage is inside of the test. So if anything goes wrong, the test will fail normally, not the pytest's module importing (as it would happen if the decorated function is declared on the module level, which you probably already noticed).

Comment: yes I think your 1st solution looks much clearer as in what I am actually testing and it shows every step as well. for 2nd solution, however I prefer to put the fixture inside conftest and just call it in my test.

Comment: but the 2nd solution does clearly the intent of my test. :)

Comment: @stucash You are welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer ;-)

Comment: more than happy to; but could you edit your answer to include the comments by other guys? I do think that should be an important part of the correct answer to my question. They to be honest directly answered my question: pytest has called it for me. your first paragraph isn't very clear what you meant.:) I appreciate your examples though.thanks a lot!

Comment: @stucash Ah! That was not clear? I missed that, indeed. Ok, I've added a quick reference in the top.